# How to identify and remove hidden text from the PDF using PDFBox java

Tags: pdfbox

I am reading text from PDF using pdfbox library and saving it in text file. It reads hidden text as well which is not visible when PDF is viewed through PDF Reader. My requirement is to get some characteristics of these hidden text which can distinguish it from normal text.

Comment: For some ideas have a look at the [questions of D.F. Stones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9123040/d-f-stones?tab=questions) and the respective answers; here a number of options have been visited.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for sharing your views. I came across few solutions shared by you and tried applying it and it did work to remove some of the hidden text of PDF. But still there is some hidden text in the PDF which is rotated at particular angle and I need to remove that text as well from the output. Could you please share some of your insights to resolve this issue?

Comment: FYI.. I used the solution mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908124/pdfbox-removing-invisible-text-by-clip-filling-paths-issue

Comment: *"But still there is some hidden text in the PDF which is rotated at particular angle and I need to remove that text as well from the output. Could you please share some of your insights to resolve this issue?"* - Please share the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: @mkl https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFhF9y8jh_tr9POU258Fvn9WDRGdv-4-/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: The "DRAFT - UNAUDITED" in that file is drawn in white (CMYK 0 0 0 0 to be exact) very early in the page drawing process. Thus, it is *not invisible* as in *covered by something* or *outside the current clip path*, it is white text on a white background in plain sight.

Comment: Ok fine. I have another PDF which has same text in silver color. How to identify and remove text here? Could you please check and guide me? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bEcpJheSWTl29B1SGheSv34k9S6VIMeb/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: The *silver* actually is a specific gray with value 0.753 in a Gray
Gamma
2.2 XYZ **ICCBased** colorspace.

Comment: By the way: *"How to identify and remove text here?"* - By *remove text* do you mean actually removing it from the PDF (to prevent it from appearing in copy&paste from the viewer) or merely from the text you extract?

Comment: I meant from text that is extracted

Comment: @mkl so how to remove this silver invisible text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible criterion for the texts to ignore in your example files is the text color, pure CMYK white in one case, 0.753 in a *Gray Gamma 2.2 XYZ* ICCBased colorspace in the other case.

So let's extend the text stripper by a color filtering option. This in particular means adding operator processors for color setting instructions as the `PDFTextStripper` by default ignores them:

```java
public class PDFFilteringTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper {
    public interface TextStripperFilter {
        public boolean accept(TextPosition text, PDGraphicsState graphicsState);
    }

    public PDFFilteringTextStripper(TextStripperFilter filter) throws IOException {
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetStrokingColorSpace());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetNonStrokingColorSpace());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetStrokingColor());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetNonStrokingColor());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetStrokingColorN());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetNonStrokingColorN());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetStrokingDeviceGrayColor());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetNonStrokingDeviceGrayColor());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetStrokingDeviceRGBColor());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetNonStrokingDeviceRGBColor());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetStrokingDeviceCMYKColor());
        addOperator(new org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.SetNonStrokingDeviceCMYKColor());

        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
        PDGraphicsState graphicsState = getGraphicsState();
        if (filter.accept(text, graphicsState))
            super.processTextPosition(text);
    }

    final TextStripperFilter filter;
}
```

*([PDFFilteringTextStripper](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/PDFFilteringTextStripper.java) class)*

Using that text stripper class, we can filter the white text from the first example PDF like this:

```java
float[] colorToFilter = new float[] {0,0,0,0};

PDDocument document = ...;
PDFFilteringTextStripper stripper = new PDFFilteringTextStripper((text, gs) -> {
    PDColor color = gs.getNonStrokingColor();
    return color == null || !((color.getColorSpace() instanceof PDDeviceCMYK) && Arrays.equals(color.getComponents(), colorToFilter));
});
String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

*([ExtractFilteredText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractFilteredText.java#L42) test `testExtractNoWhiteText...`)*

Similarly we can filter the gray text from the second example PDF like this:

```java
float[] colorToFilter = new float[] {0.753f};

PDDocument document = ...;
PDFFilteringTextStripper stripper = new PDFFilteringTextStripper((text, gs) -> {
    PDColor color = gs.getNonStrokingColor();
    return color == null || !((color.getColorSpace() instanceof PDICCBased) && Arrays.equals(color.getComponents(), colorToFilter));
});
String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

*([ExtractFilteredText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/ExtractFilteredText.java#L71) test `testExtractNoGrayText...`)*

---

In a comment you asked

> A quick question- this text in 0.753 in a Gray Gamma 2.2 XYZ ICCBased colorspace - invisible text? Or is it just because of the colorspace, text is not visible in PDF?

**It is visible!** (Thus, strictly speaking you should *not* remove it from the extracted text.)

It merely is quite small. On the title page zoom in on the year "2016":

[image: "2016" with small "DRAFT - UNAUDITED"]

Comment: This worked, thanks :) A quick question- this text in 0.753 in a Gray Gamma 2.2 XYZ ICCBased colorspace - invisible text? Or is it just because of the colorspace, text is not visible in PDF?

Comment: I'll have to verify. I'll look later.

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks again :)

Comment: See the edit to my answer, it is not invisible at all, merely very small.

Comment: Ohh yes its so strange. Could you please check this PDF ? It has some text in footer "Green bonds - Made by KfW...." This text is searchable and color is dimgray but not visible. What could be the reason?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1epCmrJ1lsM9o5X_m3xgVVqhmyYY6Lf1O/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: In the content stream that footer text up to and including the page number is drawn first, then a large white rectangle covering it, making that footer text invisible, and only then the text you see is drawn.

Comment: ok so how to ignore this text while doing extraction since its not visible in PDF and so not required to be extracted.

Comment: Use the [`PDFVisibleTextStripper`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/extract/PDFVisibleTextStripper.java) originally from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396555/1729265). You can adapt the `PDFFilteringTextStripper` here to extend the `PDFVisibleTextStripper` instead of the `PDFTextStripper`.

Comment: Ok will try that. Meanwhile i have a quick question - if some text is truly invisible in PDF then is it true that we will always get a negative getYDirAdj() value for that text?

Comment: What do you mean by "*truly* invisible"?

Comment: lol.. I mean the text which is not of white color on white background or something with too small font size and thus is invisible.

Comment: Well, there are still numerous ways for text to be not visible, and only a few of them imply a negative `getYDirAdj()` value (namely those that have the text at the top, outside the page borders). The others rely on details like a text rendering mode drawing nothing (mode 3 - *invisible* - or 7 - *clip-path*), a blend mode resulting in no change (e.g. in mode *Lighten* or *Difference* drawing anything black makes no difference.), clip paths the text is drawn outside of, font files with only blank glyphs, etc etc etc

Comment: Ohh ok got it. Thanks a lot for sharing this info. Is there any more reference material or links online where I can read more about this stuff "The others rely on details like a text rendering mode drawing nothing (mode 3 - invisible - or 7 - clip-path), a blend mode resulting in no change (e.g. in mode Lighten or Difference drawing anything black makes no difference.), clip paths the text is drawn outside of, font files with only blank glyphs, etc etc etc"

Comment: I use the PDF specification ISO 32000. A copy of the first version (from 2008) has been published by Adobe for free download (merely the ISO headers are missing), simply google for "PDF32000_2008". The second version (from 2017) is not officially available for free.

Comment: Ok I will refer it. Thanks for sharing and thanks for all the help so far :)